# SQL Server Job Agent - enable it in the Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can someone tell me please how can I enable the SQL Server Agent in the Object Explorer of my Management Studio interface?

I have the 18.9 version of Management Studio and I cannot find anywhere how to enable this option and then to actually create a Job. Any help?

Below you can see what I'm looking for:

[image: SQL Agent Picture from Object Explorer]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

If you are running LocalDB or Express edition of SQL Server, there is no SQL Server Agent. It is not a problem of your management studio but it is the limited functionality of the server you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

As Vojtěch states, the issue is with the server, not your version of SSMS.

As stated, if you are using Express Edition, Agent is not present at all. If you are using any other edition of SQL Server (Standard / Enterprise / Developer) then the agent exists but you still may not see it in object explorer.

The reason for not seeing it in any of the "full" editions is lack of permissions in the msdb database - the account you are logged with in SSMS will need to be in the `SQLAgentUserRole` at a minimum to see the SQL Server Agent node